# Exact statistic for Wilcoxon rank-sum / Man-Whitney-U test

Tags: python, statistics

I want to compute a ranksum test statistic for a small sample (n=32). `scipy.stats.mannwhitneyu` uses a normal approximation for the test statistic and the associated p-value (see [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.mannwhitneyu.html#scipy.stats.mannwhitneyu)). For small samples, this might be misleading.

Is there a way in python to compute *exact* test statistics and/or associated p-values (as described [here](https://www.real-statistics.com/non-parametric-tests/wilcoxon-rank-sum-test/wilcoxon-rank-sum-exact-test/), just not in excel of course)?

[R has such an option, see [here](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/wilcox.test.html) but I would prefer to stay in python.]

Comment: Pingouin statistical package perhaps

Answer (score 0):

Looks like [pingouin](https://pingouin-stats.org/generated/pingouin.wilcoxon.html#pingouin.wilcoxon) deploys straightforward brute-force approach. On small samples it indeed gives you different results for p-value

Code, Python 3.9 Win10 x64

```
import numpy as np
import pingouin as pg

import scipy.stats as st

x = [20, 22, 19, 20, 22, 18, 24, 20, 19, 24, 26, 13]
y = [38, 37, 33, 29, 14, 12, 20, 22, 17, 25, 26, 16]

print(pg.wilcoxon(x, y, tail='two-sided'))

st.wilcoxon(x, y, zero_method='wilcox', alternative='two-sided')
```